# Having Trouble Encrypting on iOS and decrypting on Node.js using RAW RSA

Tags: ios, node.js, encryption, rsa

I am trying to encrypt something on the iOS side and decrypt it on my node.js server. On the server, I am using the library forge. I was able to encrypt something and decrypt it all on node.js, and that worked. I encrypted like this: `const encryptedPassword = publicKey.encrypt(password, 'RAW');` and decrypted like this: `const password = privateKey.decrypt(encryptedPassword, 'RAW');`.

Now, instead of encrypting in the server, I would like to encrypt on my iOS app, but still decrypt using the same way. I found this library, swift-rsautils. https://github.com/btnguyen2k/swift-rsautils/blob/master/Swift-RSAUtils/RSAUtils.swift It has this function called `encryptWithRSAKey`, which is what I am using. Since it is raw encryption, I tried to pass in padding SecPaddingNone. However, unfortunately it doesn't work and I am unable to decrypt on the the server. The error message is invalid length, and the length of the base64 data does seem a lot bigger. Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

Here is my iOS code:

```
let dataString = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let certificateLabel = "certificate"
let certificateRef = self.getCertificateFromKeyChain(certificateLabel)
let certificateData = self.getDataFromCertificate(certificateRef)
let cryptoImportExportManager = CryptoExportImportManager()
let publicKeyRef = cryptoImportExportManager.importPublicKeyReferenceFromDERCertificate(certificateData)
let encryptedData = self.encryptWithRSAKey(data, rsaKeyRef: publicKeyRef!, padding: SecPadding.None)
let base64EncryptedString = encryptedData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
```

I am then sending this base64 encrypted string to the server and trying to decrypt using the private key. It doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Please don't use RAW RSA. This textbook RSA is completely insecure. RSA needs a secure padding like OAEP. Remember that RSA can only encrypt a limited amount of data. If you want to encrypt data that is larger than the key size, you need to use [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

Comment: Is there a reason for using RSA asymetric encryption as opposed to symetric encryption such as AES and/or using HTTPS?

Comment: I have already set up everything to use RSA. Is RSA really that bad?

Comment: Let's just assume that I know what I am doing or am just experimenting. How can I do Raw RSA encryption on the iOS?

Comment: RSA is substantially slower and the data that can be encrypted is limited to less than the key size. The keys are much longer for equlivelent security: AES 128-bits is equlivelent to RSA 3072-bits. AES uses a single key and RSA used two keys. Some reasons for choosing RSA is the need for seperate keys public and private and PKI (Public Key Infrastructure). Lacking a compelling need for RSA use AES.

Comment: I have already set up RSA, and am using it for just a password. Hence, I don't really care about the size of the data.

Comment: @MehtaiPhoneApps Your main problem is the lack of padding... RSA without proper padding is insecure and should not be used.  If you want something to be "secure" you should do it properly.

Comment: I have a reason for doing raw RSA, can you please explain me how to do it in iOS? Please?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the answer to your exact question, since I haven't used that specific library, but I have played a little with encryption in javascript and node.js.

I was able to implement the eccjs library which is the Stanford Javascript Crypto Library (SJCL) built with asymmetric elliptical curve support.

On the node.js side:

```
var ecc = require('eccjs');
var cryptoKeys = ecc.generate(ecc.ENC_DEC); //crypto_keys.enc is the pubic key for encoding. crypto_keys.dec is the private key for decoding.
//send the public key to the client
app.get('/PublicKey', function(req, res){
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    res.setHeader('Expires', '-1');
    res.setHeader('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
    res.send('var publicKey = ' + JSON.stringify(cryptoKeys.enc) + ';');    
});

//authenticate a user name and a password (encrypted by client) against the domain controller
app.get('/Authenticate', function(req, res){
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
    var url = "ldap://na-us-dc01.am.corp.airliquide.com";
    var userPrincipalName = req.query.username + "@US-AIRLIQUIDE";
    try
    {
        var cipherMessage = JSON.parse(req.query.encryptedPassword);
        var password = ecc.decrypt(cryptoKeys.dec, cipherMessage);

        //... Authentication goes here ...
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.log("Error with authentication: ",err);
        res.send("Error with authentication: " + JSON.stringify(err,null,' '));
    }
});
```

In the client:

```
<script src="ecc.js"></script>
<script src="../PublicKey"></script> <!-- This returns the variable publicKey which has been set equal to the server's public key -->
<script>

function login() {
    var plainTextPassword = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var cipherTextPassword = ecc.encrypt(publicKey, plainTextPassword);
    var username = document.getElementById('name').value;
    console.log(ecc, publicKey, cipherTextPassword);
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = (function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            console.log("Response: " + xhttp.responseText);
        }
    }).bind(this);
    xhttp.open("GET", "../Authenticate?username=" + username + "&encryptedPassword=" + JSON.stringify(cipherTextPassword), true);
    xhttp.send();   
}

</script>
```

I'm sure this solution is not perfectly secure and I ended up not using it, and instead implemented HTTPS. However this should provide you with the necessary pieces to do your own asymmetric encryption if that's your ultimate goal.

Comment: My problem was doing it on iOS. I know how to do raw rsa and have done it other places, just can't get it to work on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

SecPadding.None has been removed from Swift3 and the code of Swift-RSAUtils has changed so I cannot reproduce your problem.
However I am able to encrypt and then decrypt data with the following code:

```
let data = "Data to be encrypted".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
let e = RSAUtils.encryptWithRSAKey(data, rsaKeyRef: publicSecKeyRef, padding: SecPadding())
let d = try! RSAUtils.decryptWithRSAPrivateKey(encryptedData: e!, privkeyBase64: privkey)
```

Can you try again with latest version of Swift-RSAUtils at https://github.com/btnguyen2k/swiftutils ?

Edit: I noticed that you got error "invalid message length". Be noted that RSA cannot encrypt a very large amount of data in one go. It can encrypt a message up to `key's size - 11` length.
To workaround that limitation, Swift-RSAUtils splits the long data into small chunks, encrypts each chunk and merges them all together. So, at server side, you should do similarly: split the encrypted data into chunks of `key's size`, decrypts each one and merges them to the final result.

Comment: I figured out how to do it, the problem was that the library was adding padding even if it was SecPadding.None, but the creator fixed it.